# Android GPS onLocationChanged never called

Tags: android, gps, locationlistener

I have an android application and I would like to obtain the location.

For this I follow the android documentation, but it doesn't work. The onLocationChanged method is never called.

```
public class GPSTestActivity extends Activity
{   
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "GPS available", 3000).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "GPS not available", 3000).show();
    }

    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener()
    {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
        {
            System.out.println("RECEIVED LOCATION");
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
        {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
        {
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
        {
        }


    };

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
}
}
```

In the AndroidManifest.mf I've include the permision:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

I'm trying to test the application with the emulator in DDMS console. I set a longitude and a latitude, then presss the send button, but the onLocationChanged method is not called.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank in advance

Comment: set the mock location permission in androidmanifest.xml file for mock location

Comment: Thanks, but I have added the mock location permission but it doesn't work

Comment: try to `Override` your methods `onLocationChanged`, `onStatusChanged`, `onProviderEnabled` and `onProviderDisabled`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem.

I was testing with Android 2.3.3. and there is a bug. Testing with Google API (Level 10) works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

put parms to the call:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10f, locationListener);
```